# How to make half rounded border?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield, rounded-corners

I have a RoundPanel class that extends JPanel and provides a rounded appearance.

```
JPanel user_icon = new RoundPanel(8);
user_icon.setBackground(Color.decode("#363b41"));
user_icon.setBorder(null);
user_icon.setBounds(160, 135, 40, 46);
container.add(user_icon);
user_icon.setLayout(null);
```

```
public class RoundPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Shape shape;
    
    public RoundPanel(int size) {
        setOpaque(false);
    }
    
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         g.setColor(getBackground());
         g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1, 8, 8);
         super.paintComponent(g);
    }
    
    protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
         g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1, 8, 8);
    }
    
    public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
         if (shape == null || !shape.getBounds().equals(getBounds())) {
             shape = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1, 8, 8);
         }
         return shape.contains(x, y);
    }
}
```

want to modify it to have only the left corners rounded. (Half rounded, Half none)

Comment: You're going to have to role your own implementation.  I suggest making use of the ["shapes" API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html), for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233928/how-to-set-a-3d-border-for-a-jdialog-with-rounded-corners/12234240#12234240) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53644608/raisd-border-in-jpanel/53648853#53648853)

Comment: Prefer to modify my code.

Comment: And, given previous examples, you should be able to modify your own code - it's been asked and answered before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would, strongly, recommend taking the time to read through [Working with Geometry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html), actually, I also recommend taking the time to read through the entire [2D Graphics trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/index.html) while you're at it.

No one example/solution will ever meet your requirements 100%, you need to be prepared to put in the time to try different solutions and adapt the ones you like to your needs, this is the mark of a good developer.

So, with a little bit of experimentation (and a lot of reading through my previous answers) I was able to come up with...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    protected class TestPane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 300);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            RoundedShape shape = new RoundedShape(
                    20,
                    100, 200,
                    RoundedShape.Corner.TOP_LEFT,
                    RoundedShape.Corner.TOP_RIGHT,
                    RoundedShape.Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
                    RoundedShape.Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT
            );
            g2d.translate(10, 10);
            g2d.draw(shape);

            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    public class RoundedShape extends Path2D.Double {

        enum Corner {
            TOP_LEFT, TOP_RIGHT, BOTTOM_LEFT, BOTTOM_RIGHT;
        }

        private double radius = 20;
        private Set<Corner> corners;
        private Dimension size;

        public RoundedShape(double radius, int width, int height, Corner... corners) {
            this.corners = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(corners));
            this.radius = radius;
            this.size = new Dimension(width, height);

            build();
        }

        protected void build() {
            moveTo(0, 0);
            if (corners.contains(Corner.TOP_LEFT)) {
                moveTo(0, radius);
                curveTo(0, radius, 0, 0, radius, 0);
            }
            if (corners.contains(Corner.TOP_RIGHT)) {
                lineTo(size.width - radius, 0);
                // Draw the curve here
                curveTo(size.width - radius, 0,
                        size.width, 0,
                        size.width, radius);
            } else {
                lineTo(size.width, 0);
            }
            if (corners.contains(Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT)) {
                lineTo(size.width, size.height - radius);
                // Draw the curve here
                curveTo(size.width, size.height - radius,
                        size.width, size.height,
                        size.width - radius, size.height);
            } else {
                lineTo(size.width, size.height);
            }
            if (corners.contains(Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT)) {
                lineTo(radius, size.height);
                // Draw the curve here
                curveTo(radius, size.height,
                        0, size.height,
                        0, size.height - radius);
            } else {
                lineTo(0, size.height);
            }
            closePath();
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest having a look at [Drawing a curve in Java using mouse drag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847352/drawing-a-curve-in-java-using-mouse-drag/48847604#48847604), as working with Bézier curve always confuses me.

You may also consider look at:

- [How to draw custom rounded rectangles in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321732/how-to-draw-custom-rounded-rectangles-in-java/20321954#20321954)

Comment: Could this `RoundedShape` break down if its width and height are different?

Comment: @aterai I've not tested it, but I don't think so, since the individual parts of the shape are based on the size and radius value.  Now, if your radius values are ridiculously large and your size ridiculously small, you'll run into trouble, but, you could put in some logic which reduces the radius to a more manageable state (ie half the width or height, which ever is smallest)

Comment: Oh, it's not the arcwidth and archeight of the radius, but the width and height of the rectangle itself.
For example, change the `RoundedShape shape = ...` line in `Main.java` to `new RoundedShape(20, 200, 100, RoundedShape.Corner.TOP_RIGHT, RoundedShape.Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT);` for clarity.

Comment: @aterai Whoops, got the anchor points reversed (height <-> width), now fixed